# Regex Negative Lookbehind works in PCRE but not in Python

Tags: python, regex, pcre, negative-lookbehind

The pattern `(?<!(asp|php|jsp))\?.*` works in PCRE, but it doesn't work in Python.

So what can I do to get this regex working in Python?  (Python 2.7)

Comment: How does it not work?  Does it give an error?  If so, post the error.  Does it not match what you expect?  If so, post the code where you use it and show the output you get vs. what you expect.

Comment: Here is the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for the re  module, clearly state support of negative lookbehind assertions.

Comment: Negative lookbehinds work in re as long as all alternatives have the same length. So this works `(?<!asp|php|jsp)`, but not this `(?<!asp|php|html)`.

Comment: @georg how would you accomodate for different length strings with lookbehinds?

Comment: @physlexic: regex (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) can do this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It works perfectly fine for me. Are you maybe using it wrong? Make sure to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'somestring.asp?1=123'
>>> re.search(r"(?<!(asp|php|jsp))\?.*", s)
>>> s = 'somestring.xml?1=123'
>>> re.search(r"(?<!(asp|php|jsp))\?.*", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002DCB098>
```

Which is exactly how your pattern should behave. As glglgl mentioned, you can get the match if you assign that `Match` object to a variable (say `m`) and then call `m.group()`. That yields `?1=123`.

By the way, you can leave out the inner parentheses. This pattern is equivalent:

```
(?<!asp|php|jsp)\?.*
```

Comment: ... and `re.search(r"(?<!(asp|php|jsp))\?.*", s).group()` gives `'?1=123'`.