# Grab numbers that are 6 long except those after a specific phrase in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python in case it matters.

I am trying to grab all 6-long numbers from a file: `([0-9]{6})` which works fine.

But I want to ignore any such numbers if they are immediately preceded by "Obsolete #:".

So for example `Obsolete #:748275` would get ignored, but not `something else 957252`.

I am trying stuff like `[^Obsolete #:]([0-9]{6})` but it simply doesn't work / grabs the number anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Regex Negative Lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947933/python-regex-negative-lookbehind). More info here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [negative lookbehind.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

`(?<!Obsolete #:)\b(\d{6})\b`
Try it: https://regex101.com/r/RsMoi9/1

Explanation:

- `(?<!Obsolete #:)`: Negative lookbehind. Do not match anything that comes after this.
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(\d{6})`: Capture six digits
- `\b`: Another word boundary

Comment: I had been trying `(?!Obsolete #:)(\d{6})` - why does this fail but yours works?

Comment: @user525966 `(?!Obsolete #:)` is a negative look _ahead_, useful if you want to match something that is _not followed_ by `Obsolete #:`